# asp.net MVC Register view with additional fields

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a Register view - where only people in the "administrators" role can create new users.  I'm using the standard VS2012 register view - but I also want to add a drop down, to allow the admin to select which role the new user will belong to.

When the form is posted back, using the controller Register(RegisterModel model) - how do I grab the drop down list, with the selected role and populate it here:

```
Roles.AddUserToRole(model.UserName, XXXXXXXXXX);
```

View:

```
 <fieldset>
    <legend>Registration Form</legend>
    <ol>
        <li>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName)
        </li>
        <li>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email)
        </li>
        <li>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)
        </li>
        <li>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword)
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword)
        </li>
        <li>
            Type of user:
            @Html.DropDownList("roleName")
        </li>

    </ol>
    <input type="submit" value="Register" />
</fieldset>
```

Controller:

```
 //
    // POST: /Account/Register

    [Authorize(Roles = "admin")]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Attempt to register the user
            MembershipCreateStatus createStatus;
            Membership.CreateUser(model.UserName, model.Password, model.Email, passwordQuestion: null, passwordAnswer: null, isApproved: true, providerUserKey: null, status: out createStatus);

            if (createStatus == MembershipCreateStatus.Success)
            {
                // Add user to selected role
                Roles.AddUserToRole(model.UserName, XXXXXXXXXX);
                // Don't want to login the user - as "admin" is creating this user
                // FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, createPersistentCookie: false);
                //ViewBag.created = "yes";
                return RedirectToAction("UserList","Account");
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", ErrorCodeToString(createStatus));
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

Thank you,

Mark

Answer (score 3):

Got frustrated - went for a break - and came back:

```
Roles.AddUserToRole(model.UserName, Request.Form["roleName"]);
```

Answer to the question - take a break!!!

Thanks, Mark

Comment: Sometimes, go into woods. When you body moving (physically) you get ideas better than when you sitting pulling your hair off. Proven time and again. 
"Albert Einstein also did his best thinking near a shower. ("Why is it I always get my best ideas while shaving?")"

Answer (score 1):

```
    <li>
        Type of user:
        @Html.DropDownListFor( x => x.roleName, new { List = new LookupUtils.AvailableRolesList(Model.UserId), "Value", "Text", Model.roleName })
    </li>
```

LookupUtils is a static class have:

```
    public static List<SelectListItem> AvailableRolesList( int UserId )
    {
        var dataContext = new YourDataContext(  );
        var data = dataContext.GetRolesForUserFn( UserId ).ToList();

        var result = ( from res in data
                       select new SelectListItem()
                                  {
                                      Text = res.RoleName,
                                      Value = res.RoleId.ToString()
                                  } ).ToList();

        return result;
    }
```